# Get PowerShell Output To A Variable

Tags: powershell

Guys I have this script that almost works, it works correctly in a powershell window but not if I call it using the command line below declaring the UserName variable

UserLookup.ps1 -UserName username

Here's the script

```
param ( $UserName )
$Searcher =  [ADSISearcher]"(sAMAccountName=$UserName)"
$searcher.SearchRoot='GC://dc=corp,dc=domain,dc=com'
$UserResult =  $Searcher.FindOne()
If ($UserResult -eq $Null) {0}
Else {1}
```

If I run it like this in the powershell window its fine

```
param ( $UserName )
$Searcher =  [ADSISearcher]"(sAMAccountName=username)"
$searcher.SearchRoot='GC://dc=corp,dc=domain,dc=com'
$UserResult =  $Searcher.FindOne()
If ($UserResult -eq $Null) {0}
Else {1}
```

Result

---

PS D:\PowerShellScripts> D:\PowerShellScripts\UserLookup.ps1
1

---

What this should do is take a variable passed to the script and searches a global catalogue for a user account to test if it exists or not. I then need to get the 1 or 0 result into my $UserNameResult variable but I can't figure out how to do it.

Any help gratefully received

parto

Comment: What happens when you call the script with the parameter `-UserName username`? Do you get no output or an error?  If you're trying to catch the output have your tried `$UserNameResult = .\UserLookup.ps1 -UserName someusername`?

Answer (score 0):

I would assign the variable directly to the script.

```
$UserNameResult = .\UserLookup.ps1 -UserName $username
```